# SSAS Rollup Measure for Parent in Flattened Ragged Hierarchy - Optimal Solution

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, dax, ssas-tabular

Okay, so, I have a flattened hierarchy as a dimension table in a cube in the data warehouse and I need to roll-up a measure to all parents to the top of the hierarchy.

A little data to show you what I'm trying to accomplish..

## DimWBS

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| DimWBSKey  |       Name         |     SortableWBS     |
|------------|--------------------|---------------------|
|     1      | Recapitalization   | 0050                |
|     2      | Recap Child        | 0050.0001           |
|     3      | Recap Grandchild   | 0050.0001.0002      |
|     4      | Recap GG           | 0050.0001.0002.0003 |
|     5      | Recap GG 2         | 0050.0001.0002.0004 |
|     6      | Program Management | 0050.0002           |
|     7      | Program Child      | 0050.0002.0002      |
|     8      | Program Grandchild | 0050.0002.0002.0001 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

## FactBudget

```
---------------------------
| DimWBSKey  |   Budget   |
|------------|------------|
|     4      |  $150,000  |
|     5      |  $25,000   |
|     8      |  $50,000   |
---------------------------
```

#### Expected Output

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| DimWBSKey  |       Name         |     SortableWBS     |   Budget   |
|------------|--------------------|---------------------|------------|
|     1      | Recapitalization   | 0050                |  $225,000  |
|     2      | Recap Child        | 0050.0001           |  $175,000  |
|     3      | Recap Grandchild   | 0050.0001.0002      |  $175,000  |
|     4      | Recap GG           | 0050.0001.0002.0003 |  $150,000  |
|     5      | Recap GG 2         | 0050.0001.0002.0004 |  $25,000   |
|     6      | Program Management | 0050.0002           |  $50,000   |
|     7      | Program Child      | 0050.0002.0002      |  $50,000   |
|     8      | Program Grandchild | 0050.0002.0002.0001 |  $50,000   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I just do a basic MDX query like below, I get NULLS (as expected) for all of the parents.

```
SELECT {
    [Measures].[Budget]
} ON COLUMNS, {
    [DimWBS].[SortableWBS].[SortableWBS].MEMBERS
} ON ROWS FROM [G2 Summary]
```

Generates this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| DimWBSKey  |       Name         |     SortableWBS     |   Budget   |
|------------|--------------------|---------------------|------------|
|     1      | Recapitalization   | 0050                |    NULL    |
|     2      | Recap Child        | 0050.0001           |    NULL    |
|     3      | Recap Grandchild   | 0050.0001.0002      |    NULL    |
|     4      | Recap GG           | 0050.0001.0002.0003 |  $150,000  |
|     5      | Recap GG 2         | 0050.0001.0002.0004 |  $25,000   |
|     6      | Program Management | 0050.0002           |    NULL    |
|     7      | Program Child      | 0050.0002.0002      |    NULL    |
|     8      | Program Grandchild | 0050.0002.0002.0001 |  $50,000   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are a couple things I have tried already unsuccessfully

1. Just rolling up these values in the SQL stored procedures (i.e. pre-calculating the totals at each level of the hierarchy) before I populate the cube. This was a huge performance hit.
2. Creating a hierarchy in the DimWBS table using PATHITEM and calculating using DESCENDANTS. I was unable to successfully leverage these functions correctly. Maybe I'm missing something here, but I would like to avoid having to do this because it required me to create a static 12 level hierarchy.

If it helps, I do have the ParentWBSKey in the DimWBS table, though I didn't visualize it here.

So, my question is.. what is the best method for rolling up the budget measure in a flattened ragged hierarchy?

Comment: In the expected outlet do you really want to mix hierarchy levels?  A casual reader of the report might infer a total budget of $900k ($250 + $175k + $175k, etc).

Comment: We are using the recursive parent-child hierarchy functionality in SSRS so the data actually displays hierarchically, so, in the report, it'll look logical and it'll total correctly.